# Asp.net Web API : No action was found on the controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using Visual Studi0 2010. In my `WebApiConfig.cs` file I have below config, I can map these two urls `/Values` and `/Values/1`. It is working fine.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id= RouteParameter.Optional  } 
        );
```

Since I wanted to my custom URL like `/Values/Machines` and `/Values/Machines/100`, I changed above setting to below.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {action="get", id= RouteParameter.Optional  } 
        );
```

It is now mapping below urls except this one, `/Values/1`. Please let me know what I am missing.

```
1./Values
2./Values/Machines
3./Values/Machines/100
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can I take a look at your ValueController?

Answer (score 2):

It is expected behavior. According to your new Route the first parameter `Values` is expected to be a Controller name, and second parameter `1` is expected to be an Action, but you don't have an action with the name `1`

In order to get to the Action you need the url with you new route should be like so: `/Values/Index/1`

You could do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "IndexWithParam",
    url: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default", // Route name
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In this case if the Url is like this: `/Values/1`, it will hit first route and redirect it to `/Values/Index/1`. Note that I've placed a constraint on this route that makes sure that second parameter is a number.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way of achieving this ? By changing the MapHttpRoute or having more than one MapHttpRoute ? Please advice.